# Delete lines in file that have a date older than x

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, stream

I can read an entire file into memory like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename='peptides.txt'
filelines=`cat $filename`

ten_days_ago="$(date)"

for line in $filelines ; do
    date_of="$(echo "$line" | jq -r '.time')"
    if [[ "$ten_days_ago" > "$date_of" ]]; then
       # delete this line
    fi
done
```

the problem is:

1. I may not want to read the whole file into memory
2. If I stream it line by line with bash, how can I store which line to delete from? I would delete lines 0 to x, where line x has a date equal to 10 days ago.

A binary search would be appropriate here - so maybe bash is not a good solution to this? I would need to find the number of lines in the file, divide by two and go to that line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use binary search only if the file is sorted.

You do not need to read the whole file into memory; you can process it line by line:

```
while read line
do
   ....
done <$filename
```

And: Yes, I personally would not use shell scripting for this kind of problems, but this is of course a matter of taste.

Comment: sure but how do you remove lines in the file in place

Comment: What does "in place" mean here? You have a line oriented file, so you always have to read in somehow and write out a modified file.

Comment: using write() you should be able to modify a file in place - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html

Comment: @AlexanderMills : But this requires that the data written is exactly the same size as the data which is going to be replaced. Unless the lines in your input file have all the same length, this won't be the case. Even then, "removing" does not make sense. What do you fill the gap with? The best you could do is to move all subsequent lines a bit in front; not a very efficient approach. If you *really* want to do I/O within a file - i.e. treat the file as a set of records - I wouldn't recommend `bash` for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show what the input file looks like but judging by your jq its JSON data.

With that said this is how i would do it

```
today=$(date +%j)
tenDaysAgo=$(date --date="10 day ago" +%j)

#This is where you would create the data for peptides.txt
#20 spaces away there is a date stamp so it doesn't distract you
echo "Peptides stuff                    $today" >> peptides.txt

while read pepStuff; do
    if [ $pepStuff == $tenDaysAgo ]; then
        sed -i "/.*$pepStuff/d" peptides.txt
    fi
done < <(awk '{print $3}' peptides.txt)
```